# Erlang coding standards and good practices

Tags: coding-style, erlang

My team is learning some Erlang in my new job. Right now we have some code made, but the code is beginning to get a little messy and not consistent.

I'd like to know if there are coding standards that are followed by the Erlang community and can be used as a baseline. Things like how to indent, naming of variables and functions, how to structure modules, etc.

Also, is there any tool that will check those parameters? I am thinking in PEP8 or PyFlakes in the Python world. I use vim and it will detect syntax errors, which is nice, but I'd like to take it a little further and try to keep a good, consistent style that we can share and make the code more readable.

UPDATE: About the comment by Kemal, I must say that is very interesting (and we'll make good use of it) but does not cover completely the subject. My problem is to *convince* a team to use a consistent code style, as consistent as possible. A good way of convince everyone is to use a coding style that is recommended by the Erlang community. Maybe it doesn't exist, but I'd like to try as simple things, like choosing CameCase over Underscored_words can greatly help to give the code a consistent look and helps readability.

Comment: Kemal Fadillah, grahamrhay, zxq9 - sorry for the downvote, but even though the linked resources are helpful, if the links become invalid, your answers are not useful anymore. Found dsmith's contribution exemplary though, because his examples may not come from an "official" source, but he took the time and effort to provide examples in a clear fashion with a generally useful advice.

Comment: From zxq9's answer: "*In cooperation with the great folks on the [erlang-questions mailing list](http://erlang.org/mailman/listinfo/erlang-questions) (who donated their time to deliver scathing criticism where appropriate, see [thread](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2016-February/087539.html)) I produced an example project of moderate size (a complete UUID implementation) specifically to embody a style that is easy read, write, and emulate. It covers general coding practices in terms of typespeccing, edoc use, and Erlang code layout and style:*" (continued in next comment)

Comment: Continuing zxq9's answer: "*Introductory article: https://zxq9.com/archives/1293 Project: https://github.com/zxq9/zuuid Docs: http://zxq9.com/projects/zuuid/docs/ The issue of in-place multi-line lambda declarations and other multiline problems VS use of labels in source (with comparisons in compiled code) is addressed here: https://zxq9.com/archives/1337.*"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, there is this https://web.archive.org/web/20211013164839/http://www.erlang.se/doc/programming_rules.shtml. It's pretty comprehensive.

Comment: Mmmm, it looks very vague. Is more generic recommendations than specific for Erlang for the most part.

Comment: Vague? There are lots of erlang specific recommendations there and they don't look "vague" to me.

Comment: I agree that the advice in that page is probably more important than how many spaces you use.

Comment: This link seems to no longer exist; do you know if there is an updated link?

Comment: @JoshK Thankfully it's archived on the wayback machine. I've updated the link in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of one. Which is more readable to you?  This:

```
init([]) ->
   AChild = {'AName',{'AModule',start_link,[]},
         permanent,2000,worker,['AModule']},
   {ok,{{one_for_all,0,1}, [AChild]}}.
```

or this:

```
init([]) ->
   AChild = {
      'AName',
      {'AModule', start_link, []},
      permanent,
      2000,
      worker,
      ['AModule']
   },
   {
      ok, 
      {
         {one_for_all,0,1}, 
         [AChild]
      }
   }.
```

or this:

```
init([]) ->
   AChild = { 'AName'
            , {'AModule', start_link, []}
            , permanent
            , 2000
            , worker
            , ['AModule'] }
   { ok, 
      { {one_for_all,0,1}
      , [AChild] } }.
```

I like the last one, but consistency is most important. So I suggest defining a standard that works for you.

Comment: I probably prefer the second one, but the question here is, is there any consensus on the Erlang community?

Comment: The second one is the one i like least... That's probably the reason there is no standard.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool called [Elvis](https://github.com/inaka/elvis) that can be used to enforce a coding style, but the default rules are those from [Inaka](https://github.com/inaka/erlang_guidelines) (the creators) rather than defaults for the Erlang community as a whole.

Comment: Hi there! Elvis is designed to be flexible enough to be able to configure the rules you want applied by specifying your own `elvis.config`. It also supports user defined rules when it is run from the shell and there are plans to support them even when running it from the command line. Hope it helps.